# Appropriate time to announce current research topics

Tags: research-process, collaboration, economics

I am currently a Ph.D. candidate in the field of economics and I'm starting to make significant head way into my research and submitting articles to journals.  I get a really strong vibe in the academic community to protect my ideas and don't leak anything until it is appropriate.  My general sense of this comes from my experience with various individual's ideas getting "scooped."  While collaboration is obviously key to academic success, I also want to be wary of announcing any current research plans until it is appropriate.

My question is : When is it appropriate to discuss current research projects and update a CV or website?

When the paper has been accepted to a journal?  After the paper has been submitted to a journal? A proposal has been drafted?  After all preliminary research has been complete?

I appreciate  your responses.

Comment: related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27472/is-there-any-research-on-the-prevalence-of-academic-theft http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20833/how-much-of-my-ongoing-unpublished-research-should-i-disclose-to-others?rq=1 http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/how-much-information-should-i-divulge-about-on-going-unpublished-research-at-a-c

Comment: This is very field-dependent (some fields are very open, others much more secretive), so I have tagged it with economics.

Answer (score 1):

In the field of economics, I believe you are safe to go out with your paper and discuss it after you have produced a working paper or presented it in a conference.